# Installed dart sass on Mac, but receive error sass: command not found when trying to use it

Tags: bash, sass

I installed dart sass (`dart-sass-1.26.10-macos-x64.tar.gz`) on gitHub at https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/tag/1.26.10, and followed their directions, edited my `.bash_profile` and added the line:

```
export PATH="/Users/.../dart-sass:$PATH"
(where ... is the absolute path)
```

However, when I run `sass --version` in terminal, I get the error:

```
sass: command not found
```

Thanks so much for any answers! This has become a really frustrating problem for me.

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal after editing your `.bash_profile` ? Are you running `sass` command as a user you edited `.bash_profile` for ?

Comment: Yes, I restarted my terminal after editing the .bash_profile, and the user was the same for both. I actually was able to fix the problem by editing the export path to be:    export PATH="$PATH:/Users/.../dart-sass".       I am not sure why this fixed the problem, but I am now able to run sass commands.